# How to implement switch with jdbc request?

Tags: controller, jmeter

I am running a jdbc query ..in which job is running from that query. I am extracting a value in parameter. Those value are either:

1. success
2. processing
3. failed

   - On success - I need to run another query
   - On processing - I need to run the query again after some delay
   - On failed- I have to stop the thread

Please help me how to implement this.

Comment: Add the code you've tried .

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) after the first JDBC Request sampler
2. Put the "parameter" reference as the "Switch Value"

   [image]
3. Add JDBC Request sampler as a child of the Switch Controller and name it `success`. Put your query there
4. Add JDBC Request sampler as a child of the Switch Controller and name it `processing`. Put your query there. Add [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the JDBC Request sampler and configure the delay there
5. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler and set it to "Stop" the "Current Thread"

   [image]

The Switch Controller will execute this or that child depending on the `${VARIABLE_FROM_JDBC}` value. See [Selection Statements in JMeter Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy/) article for more information if needed.